# Can’t login to the user that I have just created using useradd

Tags: debian

I am using Debian 8 and when I enter this in the Terminal:

```
sudo useradd -p pass test
```

I then see this in `/etc/passwd`:

```
test:x:1001:1001::/home/test:/bin/sh
```

Yet this happens:

```
su test
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

Am I going crazy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `-p` of `useradd` is not used to set plaintext password. With `-p` you are directly setting what will be stored in `/etc/shadow`. To set password on command line this way, you will have to generate a hash first, then pass it to the `useradd` utility.

Example:

Generate hash of password `bar` salted with string `foo` using the program `openssl`:

```
openssl passwd -1 -salt foo bar
```

this will produce string `$1$foo$te5SBM.7C25fFDu6bIRbX1`. If you pass it to `useradd` (be careful to add single quotes so it doesn't expand to variables!):

```
useradd -p '$1$foo$te5SBM.7C25fFDu6bIRbX1' test
```

You should be able to login as `test` with the password `bar`.

Comment: @LawlessLeopard also consider using https://stackoverflow.com/a/2151149/6350644 when the password setting phase won't be exposed somewhere potentially public.